# Using php code inside style tag

Tags: php, css

How to use php inside the style tag. I tried this but didn't work. Any idea?

```php
<style>.mypage iframe{border-radius: <?php echo get_option('my_border'); ?>; }</style>
```

Comment: if it didn't work, what did it do instead? Where are you putting this code?

Comment: inside a php file

Comment: But which PHP file in what folder? The specific place you put this can matter a lot. And if it did not work, what did it do instead? Is the border radius missing? Did the page just stop? Was there an error message? We need to know